# Python function not recognizing integers

Tags: python, list, numbers, int

I am writing a function that takes 3 inputs, if all 3 inputs are floats and/or integers it returns the average of the 3, otherwise it returns them as a list.

This is what I have:

```
def list3(a,b,c):
    """if all inputs are int/float return average"""
    l = [a, b, c]
    for t in l:
        if t is int or t is float:
            s = sum(l)
            y = len(l)
            x = float(s/y)
            return x
        else:
            return(l)
```

when I input 3 integers it returns the list, how can I get it to recognize the input as integers? Thanks

Comment: If you use Python 3, then `float(s/y)` is unnecessary, because the result of the division is already a floating-point number. If you use Python 2, then `float(s/y)` must be `float(s)/y`, because `s/y` is an incorrect integer number.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I input 4 integers"? Do you pass four parameters? Python will not allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
def list3(a,b,c):
    """if all inputs are int/float return average"""
    l = [a, b, c]

    return sum(l)/len(l) if all(isinstance(t, (int, float)) for t in l) else l

list3(1, 2, 6)    # 3.0
list3('a', 1, 2)  # ['a', 1, 2]
```

**Explanation**

- `all(criteria for t in l)` applies a lazy function `all` on a generator expression, which checks if all items in `l` are integers or floats.
- `isinstance` is generally preferred to checking `type`.
- The `if` / `else` clause can be replaced by a [ternary statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use exception handling. A `TypeError` exception is raised if not all elements of `l` are numeric:

```
try:
    return float(sum(l)) / len(l) # Just in case it's Python 2.7
except TypeError:
    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal changes to get the code to work in Python 2 or 3:

```
def list3(a, b, c):
    """if all inputs are int/float return average"""
    l = [a, b, c]
    s = 0
    for t in l:
        if type(t) is int or type(t) is float:
            s += t
        else:
            return l
    y = len(l)
    x = float(s) / y
    return x
```

You just needed to compare type(t) to int or float, and convert s to float before the division.  You also have to complete testing of all list members before the return, otherwise s = sum(l)will bomb for a case like [1, 'str', 6]